# Editing file restart the server in meteor in windows

Tags: javascript, meteor

I successfully create the sample project and run in the `localhost:3030` but when I edit the file of html then the server gives the following error.

```
Meteor server restarted
events.js:71 throw arguments[1];//unhandled error event

Error: This socket is closed at Socket._write (net.js:519:19)
at Socket.write(net.js.511:15)
at Socket.HttpProxy.proxyWebSocketRequest.reverseProxy.incoming.socket.on.lib\node-http-proxy.js:515:35)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit(events.js:96:17)
at TCP.onread(net.js:397:14)
```

What is going wrong ?? Please help me out.
Thank You in advance!!!

Comment: Kill node processes if there is any. That might help.

Comment: how to kill node @Mohsen

Comment: There is nothing to do with any node processes here.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your server. This is very common issue on newer version of Meteor for Windows. Hopefully the Meteor core team will sort it out soon.

See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/513.

Comment: i switch to linux @sohel khalifa

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to Meteor 0.6.4 as this issue appears to have been fixed by the update to http-proxy.

The new version is available via https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows